# Understanding lambdas and/or predicates

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, predicate, functional-interface

I'm completely new to Java 8 and I'm trying to wrap my head around why the last test is false.

```
@Test
public void predicateTest() {
    Predicate<Boolean> test1 = p -> 1 == 1;
    Predicate<Boolean> test2 = p -> p == (1==1);

    System.out.println("test1 - true: "+test1.test(true));
    System.out.println("test1 - false: "+test1.test(false));
    System.out.println("test2 - true: "+test2.test(true));
    System.out.println("test2 - false: "+test2.test(false));
}
```

***Output***:

> test1 - true: **true**
>
> test1 - false: **true**
>
> test2 - true: **true**
>
> test2 - false: **false**

Comment: Maybe the anonymous class representation can help you understand better as to what is happening there. Made an answer for the same https://stackoverflow.com/a/53667633/1746118

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Elaboration

Your first `Predicate` i.e.

```
Predicate<Boolean> test1 = p -> 1 == 1;
```

can be represented as

```
Predicate<Boolean> test1 = new Predicate<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public boolean test(Boolean p) {
        return true; // since 1==1 would ways be 'true'
    }
};
```

So irrespective of what value you pass to the above `test` method, it would *always return true only*.

On the other hand, the second `Predicate` i.e.

```
Predicate<Boolean> test2 = p -> p == (1==1);
```

can be represented as

```
Predicate<Boolean> test2 = new Predicate<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public boolean test(Boolean p) {
        return p; // since 'p == true' would effectively be 'p'
    }
};
```

So whatever `boolean` value you would pass to the above `test` method, it *would be returned as is*.

---

And then you can correlate how the *method `test` corresponding to each instance `test1` and `test2` of the anonymous classes are invoked* and what shall be the probable output.

Comment: I like this elaboration, most useful :-)

Answer (score 3):

It's false because `p` is `false` and `1==1` is `true` so:

`false == true` evaluates to false.

In other words when you invoke this function with `false` as the argument:

```
 Predicate<Boolean> test2 = p -> p == (1==1);
```

it can be see as:

```
 Predicate<Boolean> test2 = p -> false == (1==1);
```

btw the above predicate will return whatever input you pass it, so essentially it's:

```
Predicate<Boolean> test2 = p -> p;
```

Answer (score 2):

Predicate test1 = value -> 1 == 1;

Predicate test2 = value -> value == (1==1);

**Test case** :  System.out.println("test2 - false: "+test2.test(false));

**Output**: false

**Explanation**:

You are calling the test2 method with "false", so your method 's execution will be like this:

```
                   false == (1==1)  => false == true => false
```

So the final answer will be false.